# Rekall Tool : SSL Error - Certificate_verify_failed (_ssl.c:1076)

Tags: python, ssl-certificate, python3, forensics

I have a problem with SSL certificate. I would like to explain my problem.

I'm trying to install [Rekall tool](https://github.com/google/rekall) and it's memory forensic framework. I installed Python 3.7 then I created new **virtualenv** called DEV. Any new pip packages will be installed into this environment.

After that, I am going to install rekall tool (rekall/rekall-core/setup.py). When I try to install, I got this error. I am trying on Windowsx86.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzzDk.png)

Comment: You may want to consider trying to use Python 3.7.3. Not a guaranteed fix, but "the internet" claims the `SSL` module in 3.7.4 may treat certain certificates as insecure (which 3.7.3 apparently may not do).

Comment: I tried Python 3.7.3 and 3.7.4 even 2.7.16 but it doesn't work.